# Does anyone already have a .NET wrapper for ETW StartTrace?

Tags: .net, wrapper, trace, etw

I am hoping to start ETW trace sessions using .NET code directly rather than invoking command line apps.  Does anyone already have a .NET wrapper for ETW StartTrace and friends?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/EventTraceWatcher/1.0.0 has everything I need.

Comment: TraceEventSession from [TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/) is what you want to start new ETW sessions